# Need a script to send an email if Cell Value Changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need Help to create a watchdog. I'm importing a webpage with some data. and want constantly check if imported data is the same whats my reference.
So I want the script to constantly compare 2 cells and if values became different, send me (the author) the email.
Want to compare H4 and E4
[image]

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pricechecker");
  var checkprice = sheet.getRange(E2:E2);
  var currentprice = sheet.getRange(H4:H4);

    if (currentprice <= checkprice) {
      var emailAddress = "email@example.ge";  
      var message = "Discount";
      var subject = "There is a Discount on your item";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

You would need an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to automatically send email upon comparison of E4 and H4.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('compare')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function compare(e) {
  if (e.range == "E4" || "H4") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var checkPrice = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
    var currentPrice = sheet.getRange("H4").getValue();
    if (currentPrice <= checkPrice) {
      var emailAddress = "email@example.ge";  
      var message = "Discount";
      var subject = "There is a Discount on your item";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you only have to run `createSpreadsheetEditTrigger()` in Apps Script. The created trigger will run `compare()` everytime you make an edit to the spreadsheet. It will automatically check E4 and H4 and send email whether the condition is satisfied.

**Console Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks... but Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
compare @ Code.gs:10

Comment: You do not need to run ````compare()```` manually, only the create trigger function. The former will be triggered once you make edits to the sheet.